# Infinite Scroll: Browser freezes again and again during scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, infinite-scroll

for my project I have programmed an infinite scroll (index.php), which should always load content from another subpage (load.php with offset) when the user has reached the end of the page.

My problem is that when I scroll with a browser on a mobile device (tested with Firefox and Safari on iOS), the browser freezes for a short time (1-2 sec) and shortly after that it is possible to scroll again, which is very annoying.

On laptops / PCs everything works so far (tested with Firefox and Edge on Win10). However, on laptops/PCs I see that the scrollbar keeps going up and down quickly when new content is loaded and never stands still, which also looks a bit disconcerting.

I have not found a solution to my problem on the internet so far. I hope one of you can help me and possibly modify the script. Thank you! Below I have shown my code in excerpts (the project is very large, so only excerpts):

**HTML (index.php):**

```
<!-- Fallback -->
<div id="no" style="display:none">
   No Content found...
</div>

<!-- Infinity -->
<div id="inf-0"></div><div id="inf-3" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-6" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-9" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-12" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-15" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-18" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-21" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-24" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-27" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-30" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-33" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-36" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-39" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-42" style="display:none"></div><div id="inf-45" style="display:none"></div> ...

<!-- Spinner --->
<center><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x" id="spinner"></i></center>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var end = 0;
var infinity = 0;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    feed(infinity);
    infinity = infinity+3;
});

$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if(end == 0) {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 75) {
            document.getElementById("inf-"+infinity).style.display = "block";
            feed(infinity);
            infinity = infinity+3;
        }
    }
});

function feed(infinity) {
    $("#inf-" + infinity).load("load.php?off="+infinity+"&url="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href), function( response, status, xhr ) {
        if (response == "") {
            document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("inf-"+infinity).style.display = "none";
            end = 1;
        } else {
            if (response == "no") {
                document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("inf-"+infinity).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("no").style.display = "block";
                end = 1;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block";
            }
        }  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height: 400px !important" id="heighthelper">&nbsp;</div>
```

Solved the problem with adding this div to body area. Added to Javascript in the area of if response == "" or == no:

```
document.getElementById("heighthelper").style.display = "none";
```